# Drag-n-drop with QWindow

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

I have custom `QWidget` that contains custom `QWindow`. `QWindow` with OpenGL is used as a "connector" between render framework and Qt application.

Mouse and keyboard events are handled with overriding `QWindow` methods.

Pseudo-code:

```
class MyWindow : public QWindow
{
public:
  MyWindow : QWindow() { /* GL stuff init*/ }
protected:
  // mouse/keyboard event handling
  // expose event handling
  // resize event handling
  // ...
};

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
  MyWidget : QWidget()
  {
    auto window = new MyWindow();
    auto container = createWindowContainer(window);
    layout()->addWidget( container );
    setAcceptDrops( true );
  }

protected:
  // overriding drop event, but is doesn't work
};
```

Question: how to handle drop events (it doesn't matter where)?

Problems:

1. `QWindow` doesn't provide virtual methods for drag-n-drop support.
2. `QWidget::dragEnterEvent`, `QWidget::dropEvent` (and similar) are not called.
3. `QWindow` still accept mouse events, even `setMouseGrabEnabled( false );` is set.

Note: I found that call of `setMouseGrabEnabled( false );` doesn't blocks mouse events handling in `QWindow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

It is necessary to install event filter on `QWindow` and process events there (`eventFilter`).

It is possible to install event filter on `QWidget` (container) but it doesn't work on OS X. Probably it is a bug in Qt, because under Win everything is fine.