# QEvent::Drop event is never generated for QQuickView window

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qevent, eventfilter

I'm struggling with an issue that `QEvent::Drop` event is never generated for my `QQuickView` window.

I need to implement a drag'n'drop functionality, to drop files from explorer to the `QQuickView`.

As described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829679/drag-n-drop-with-qwindow), i've istalled an eventfilter for the `QQuickView` objet, and in `eventFilter()` method trying to catch required events. The `QEvent::DragMove` is being generated as expected, as i drag a file over the view. But when i drop the file on the view, the `QEvent::Drop` is not being generated. Instead, the `QEvent::DragLeave` is generated.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    Filter f;
    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->installEventFilter(&f);
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And here is a (Event)Filter class code:
(header)

```
class Filter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Filter(){};
    virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};
```

(source)

```
bool Filter::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::DragMove)
        qDebug() << "it's a drag";
    if(event->type() == QEvent::Drop)
        qDebug() << "it's a drop"; // <<-- Never reaches here
    return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleagues helped me out with this question.
Apparently you have to add a `DropArea` item to your `QML` root file, and after that the `QQuickView` will start receiving `QEvent::Drop` events.
I can not find any documentation on this case though, and i also wonder what would be more general solution for this, if you had a `QWindow` class instead.
Anyway, I'm closing this question.